# capturing active log and displaying it in text area - SWT

Tags: swt

I am building a SWT application which would trigger a long running shell process.  I am able to trigger it in a seperate thread as mentione in this [Java Lobby](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t43753.html) link.

My shell process will generate a log file.  I have to read it and show the progress of the process in a text area.  How to achieve it without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Use something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/37594490/2670892

Comment: Thanks greg-449,  I am bit confused on how to read the file recursively.  How to use the alert functionality to update my textarea.  Let me try to implement it and come back to you with fresh set of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Like the link you shared the first thing you have to launch log watcher in a separate Thread :

```
Thread one = new Thread(){
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println("start watching log.");
                  updateLog();
              }
          };

one.start();
```

After you can use WatchService to detect the log files changes then Use SWT’s Display asyncExec to display the log changes :

```
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

WatchKey key;
while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
        if (event.context().toString().endsWith(logfileName)) {

            shlLogViewer.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    logDisplay.setText(readFromFile(LOG_FILE_SIZE));
                }
            });
        }
    }
    key.reset();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Korteby for your suggestion